# How to convert an RDD (that read in a directory of text files) into dataFrame in Apache Spark in Scala?

Tags: feature-extraction, tf-idf

I'm developing a Scala feature extracting app using Apache Spark TF-IDF. I need to read in from a directory of text files. I'm trying to convert an RDD to a dataframe but I'm getting the error "value toDF() is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[streamedRDD]". This is what I have right now ...

I have spark-2.2.1 & Scala 2.1.11. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
// Creating the Spark context that will interface with Spark
val conf = new SparkConf()
           .setMaster("local")
           .setAppName("TextClassification")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

// Load documents (one per line)
val data = sc.wholeTextFiles("C:/Users/*")    
val text = data.map{case(filepath,text) => text}    
val id = data.map{case(filepath, text) => text.split("@").takeRight(1)(0)}

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

case class dataStreamed(id: String, input: String)

val tweetsDF = data
              .map{case (filepath, text) => 
                   val id = text.split("@").takeRight(1)(0)
                   val input = text.split(":").takeRight(2)(0)
                   dataStreamed(id, input)}
              .as[dataStreamed]
              .toDF()
              .cache()

// -------------------- TF-IDF --------------------
// From spark.apache.org
// URL http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("input").setOutputCol("words")
val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(tweetsDF)
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
                .setInputCol("words")
                .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")

val tf = hashingTF.transform(wordsData).cache()  // Hashed words

// Compute for the TFxIDF    
val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")
val tfidf = idf.fit(tf)
```

Data: (Text files like these in a folder is what I need read in) 
      https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw3okhaosu7i1md/cars.txt?dl=0
      https://www.dropbox.com/s/29tgqg7ifpxzwwz/Italy.txt?dl=0

Comment: Hello @kriz please avoid posting images since people can't use your existing code to provide you a solution instead they should type the whole code by themselves

Comment: @Alexandros will do thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that map function returns a type of Dataset[Row] which you assign to tweetsDF. It should be:

```
case class dataStreamed(id: String, input: String)
def test() = {

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TextClassification").setMaster("local")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  // Load documents (one per line)
  val data = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("C:\\tmp\\stackoverflow\\*")

  val dataset = spark.createDataset(data)

  val tweetsDF = dataset
    .map{case (id : String, input : String) =>
      val file = id.split("@").takeRight(1)(0)
      val content = input.split(":").takeRight(2)(0)
      dataStreamed(file, content)}
    .as[dataStreamed]

  tweetsDF.printSchema()
  tweetsDF.show(10)
}
```

First data will be an RDD(String, String) then I create a new Dataset with spark.createDataset in order to be able to use map properly together with the case class. Please note that you must define dataStreamedclass out of your method (test in this case)

Good luck

Comment: @Aleandros Biratsis, I have that but its still giving me the same error  
  val tweetsDF = data
      .map{case (filepath, text) => 
           val id = text.split("@").takeRight(1)(0)
           val input = text.split(":").takeRight(2)(0)
           dataStreamed(id, input)}
      .toDF()
      .cache()

Comment: please check the updated version @kriz otherwise you will need to paste your code instead of the image :)

Comment: Still have the error @Alexandros Biratsis . I've pasted my code.

Comment: Hi @criz could you post some sample data as well? I need to test the code with some data to check better what is the problem

Comment: Hi @Alexandros Biratsis no the issue is not sorted yet, I'm still researching this. Please have a look at my update post I've a couple of sample text file like the ones I need to process.Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hello @kriz sorry I was to busy and couldn't check it further. I can check it now though if you are still looking for a solution

Comment: @kriz I have updated my post with a new version. Let me know if it will work for you

Comment: I am glad to able to help you finally

Answer (score 0):

### We can do this with couple of commands/functions:

- **Invoke the spark/scala shell, you can use driver-memory, executor-memory, executor-cores etc as suits your job**

  spark-shell
- **Read the text file from HDFS**

  val text_rdd = sc.textFile("path/to/file/on/hdfs")
- **Convert the text rdd to DataFrame**

  val text_df = text_rdd.toDF
- **Save as plan text format in HDFS**

  text_df.saveAsTextFile("path/to/hdfs")
- **Save as splittable compressed format in HDFS**

  text_df.coalesce(1).write.parquet("path/to/hdfs")